# How can I loop through all different Product Types in Craft Commerce?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

I am trying to have a overview page where I want to loop through all available product categories in separate rows. Somehow I was only able to achieve it when I specify the type of the product. That isn't ideal since I want the customer to be able to add new product types which will be displayed in a new row then.

Something like this :

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.type('all').find() %}

{% for 'type #1' in products %}
    ...
{% endfor  %}

{% for 'type #2' in products %}
    ...
{% endfor  %}

etc..
```

thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoping this is what you are looking to do?

```
{% for productType in craft.commerce.productTypes %}

  {{ productType.name }}<br>

{% for product in craft.commerce.products.type(productType.handle).find() %}

  {{ product.title }}<br>

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```